# how to populate an Associative Array index by VARCHAR2

Tags: oracle, associative-array

I have 2 associative arrays:

- v1 index by binary integer
- v2 index by varchar2

```
type r1 is record
   ( c1 number
   , c2 varchar2(64));
type t1 is table of r1 index by binary_integer;
v1 t1;

type t2 is table of varchar2(64) index by binary_integer;
v2 t2;

counter number := 0;

type r3 is record
    ( no_visits number);
type t3 is table of r3 index by varchar2(64);
v3 t3;
```

I want to have a list (probably another associative array - `v3` with the cities from `v1` which are defined in `v2` and how many times I have visited them (the visits are defined in `v1`).

I was thinking that `v3` to be index by VARCHAR2 (the index to be the name of the cities) and contains only one value, the number of visits.

Is it possible to have implement something like:

```
begin
    v1(1).c1 := 1990;
    v1(1).c2 := 'PARIS';
    V1(2).c1 := 2000;
    V1(2).c2 := 'PARIS';
    v1(3).c1 := 2001;
    v1(3).c2 := 'PARIS';
    v1(4).c1 := 1992;
    v1(4).c2 := 'MADRID';
    v1(5).c1 := 1994;
    v1(5).c2 := 'LONDON';
    v1(6).c1 := 1998;
    v1(6).c2 := 'PRAGUE';

    v2(1) := 'PARIS';
    v2(2) := 'LONDON';
    v2(3) := 'MADRID';

    for i in 1 .. v1.count loop
        for j in 1 .. v2.count loop
            if v1(i).c2 = v2(j)
                then
                    v3(v2(j).c2) := counter + 1;

            end if;
        end loop;
    end loop;

end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize `v3` with values from `v2`, modify counting loop slightly and show results in final loop:

```
declare 
    type r1 is record ( c1 number, c2 varchar2(64));
    type t1 is table of r1 index by binary_integer;
    v1 t1;
    type t2 is table of varchar2(64) index by binary_integer;
    v2 t2;
    type r3 is record( no_visits number);
    type t3 is table of r3 index by varchar2(64);
    v3 t3;
begin
    v1(1).c1 := 1990;
    v1(1).c2 := 'PARIS';
    V1(2).c1 := 2000;
    V1(2).c2 := 'PARIS';
    v1(3).c1 := 2001;
    v1(3).c2 := 'PARIS';
    v1(4).c1 := 1992;
    v1(4).c2 := 'MADRID';
    v1(5).c1 := 1994;
    v1(5).c2 := 'LONDON';
    v1(6).c1 := 1998;
    v1(6).c2 := 'PRAGUE';

    v2(1) := 'PARIS';
    v2(2) := 'LONDON';
    v2(3) := 'MADRID';

    for i in 1..v2.count loop
        v3(v2(i)).no_visits := 0;
    end loop;

    for i in 1 .. v1.count loop
        for j in 1 .. v2.count loop
            if v1(i).c2 = v2(j) then
                    v3(v2(j)).no_visits := v3(v2(j)).no_visits + 1;
            end if;
        end loop;
    end loop;

    for i in 1..v2.count loop
        dbms_output.put_line('City: '||v2(i));
        dbms_output.put_line('Visited: '||v3(v2(i)).no_visits);
    end loop;

end;
```

Output:

```
City: PARIS
Visited: 3
City: LONDON
Visited: 1
City: MADRID
Visited: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, yes, you can do that. In this case there are some problems - for example, in the line `v3(v2(j).c2) := counter + 1;` there's no `c2` element in `v2` so you'll get a compilation error there, and in that same line the `v3` reference should be followed by `.no_visits`, but generally speaking what you're trying to do here is certainly allowed by the language.